# Hyperlinks in an view-based TableView (NSTableCellView)

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell, nstableviewcell

I have an view-based TableView with an image and a NSTextField. I've got some links inside my NSTextField and I have tried many options (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1487.html, dsclickableurltextfield) but nothing works out, because it seems that these options only fit to an cell-based tableview. I also watched the wwdc 2010 cocoa tips and tricks with an good explanation for links inside tableviews. But the custom NSTextFieldCell doesn't work for me. The mouse-events don't reach the custom class and for that reason nothings happens...

I hope you've got the right idea to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your table view's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return YES; // required for specific tracking control in our NSTextFieldCell
}
```